# How to implement a SAFEARRAY(long) parameter?

Tags: c#, c++, com, safearray

I currently have a C# method in an interface that has the following parameters when viewed in 
ITypeLib

```
HRESULT _stdcall SomeMethod ([in] Is_interface* inst, 
           [in] SAFEARRAY(long) bid);
```

The above method is in an interface and is defined in C#.After generating a type library I am attempting to create an implementation of that interface in C++. However I cannot figure out the type required for

```
[in] SAFEARRAY(long) bid
```

I am currently trying something like this

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SomeMethod (Is_interface* inst, CComSafeArray<long> bid);
```

Any suggestions on what the equivalent of `[in] SAFEARRAY(long) bid` should be for the class implementing the C# interface.

Comment: I would guess `LPSAFEARRAY` or `LPSAFEARRAY*`. You can also use variants for this.

Answer (score 3):

SAFEARRAY is the default interop type for an array.  Just a plain int[] will do.  For example:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IFoo {
    void Method(object inst, int[] array);
}
```

Produces this type library entry, obtained with OleView.exe, File + View TypeLib command:

```
[
  odl,
  uuid(2380B019-1E69-386E-BB6E-ECEF45257086),
  version(1.0),
  dual,
  oleautomation,
  custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "ClassLibrary1.IFoo")    

]
interface IFoo : IDispatch {
    [id(0x60020000)]
    HRESULT Method(
                    [in] VARIANT inst, 
                    [in] SAFEARRAY(long) array);
};
```